# Option to turn off short-circuit boolean evaluation

Tags: dwscript

So I have a user-definable script that may look something like this:

Result := (File.Size > 1000) OR (Image.Type = 'PNG');

My application requires that I know which objects were tested for, in this case File.Size and Image.Type.  To do this, in the OnEval of the respective functions, I add the Object.Method name to a string list, which I can use later.

However, if the first condition (File.Size) is met, DWScript does not evaluate the second condition.

Is there a way to force DWScript to evaluate both conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Ray

Answer (score 0):

That is a default behaviour for Delphi for ages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).